# Почему бот при команде "Эхо - сообщение" пишет только первое слова, а далее игнорирует текст

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Сам код.

````
@bot.command()
async def add(ctx,on_message):
    if ctx.author != bot.user:
        await ctx.channel.purge(limit=1)
        await ctx.send('```' + on_message + '```')
````

Фото, что выдаёт бот по команде

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всё просто. Добавьте знак » ***`*`*** перед вашим аргументом `on_message`:

```
@bot.command()
async def add(ctx, *, on_message):
```

Теперь при вводе `add какой-то текст` в аргумент будет записан весь записанный текст.